# How to hide div when I click on it

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

I would like to create an accordion, where all the tabs initially closed and whenever I click on one of them, that particular tab opens, on a second click it closes. I could open div1 but I don't know how to close it or how to generalize the openings and closings.

I also created a codepen example where you can see what I have done so far. Click on the blue div, it should open the hidden paragraph.

```
<http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbMBXd>
```

[Edited: Also when a tab open and I click on another one, the first tab should be closed as all the others except the currently open one]

Comment: Please show the relevant code directly in your question.

Comment: Will do next time @nnnnnn!

Comment: If you want to use existing, jqueryui accordion https://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible, and add **active: false;** to default hide all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your javaScript to look like this

```
    function changeSize(x){
    var div = document.getElementById(x);
    if (div.style.height == "50px"){
      switch (div.id){
        case("box1"):
          div.style.height = "auto";
          document.getElementById("box2").style.height = "50px";
          document.getElementById("box3").style.height = "50px";
          document.getElementById("box4").style.height = "50px";
          document.getElementById("box5").style.height = "50px";
          break;
        case ("box2"):
          div.style.height = "auto";
          document.getElementById("box1").style.height = "50px";
          document.getElementById("box3").style.height = "50px";
          document.getElementById("box4").style.height = "50px";
          document.getElementById("box5").style.height = "50px";
          break;
        case ("box3"):
          div.style.height = "auto";
          document.getElementById("box1").style.height = "50px";
          document.getElementById("box2").style.height = "50px";
          document.getElementById("box4").style.height = "50px";
          document.getElementById("box5").style.height = "50px";
          break;
        case ("box4"):
          div.style.height = "auto";
          document.getElementById("box1").style.height = "50px";
          document.getElementById("box3").style.height = "50px";
          document.getElementById("box2").style.height = "50px";
          document.getElementById("box5").style.height = "50px";
          break;
        case ("box5"):
          div.style.height = "auto";
          document.getElementById("box1").style.height = "50px";
          document.getElementById("box3").style.height = "50px";
          document.getElementById("box4").style.height = "50px";
          document.getElementById("box2").style.height = "50px";
          break;


      }
    } else {
     div.style.height = "50px";
     }
   }
```

Ugly but it does the job.

you can call the function from your html whenever the div is clicked

```
<div class="colorbox" id="box1" onclick="changeSize('box1')">
```

Good luck

Comment: Hey @A-Ace,


Thanks it works fine, but when I click on a div and it is opened and then I click on another one, the first div doesn't close. How can I achieve that?

Comment: answer updated, this will do what you look for, you may consider shorter solution with JQuery if its possible.

Comment: Thank you so much! That what I wanted to achieve!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, there are many ways of doing it. Following your example in codepen, can´t you to like this ?

```
    var colorvar = document.getElementById('box1');
    colorvar.addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (document.getElementById("box1").style.height == "auto") {
        document.getElementById("box1").style.height = document.getElementById("box1").style.height = "50px";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("box1").style.height = document.getElementById("box1").style.height = "auto";
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you @WilliamDallastella!

Answer (score 0):

Try this...:)

```css
.collapse > * + *{
  display:none;
}
.collapse > *{
  cursor:pointer;
}
.collapse:focus{
  outline:none;
}
.collapse:focus > * + *{
  display:block; 
}
```

```html
<div class="collapse" tabindex="1">
  <h2>Boxinum</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tincidunt ultrices arcu, ut pulvinar risus maximus sed. Quisque dolor nisl, iaculis id sem eget, molestie mollis est. Phasellus scelerisque sagittis ex, nec vestibulum turpis euismod eu. Aliquam aliquet orci et sapien euismod, vitae pellentesque velit porttitor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin rhoncus, felis non elementum ultrices, dui nisl tincidunt risus, sit amet sodales nunc dolor semper lacus. Vivamus egestas lectus id imperdiet pharetra. Nulla non sem elit. Fusce porta velit leo, nec gravida ligula auctor vitae. Sed justo sem, sodales ut imperdiet at, fringilla pharetra neque.</p>
</div>
<div class="collapse" tabindex="1">
  <h2>Boxinum</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tincidunt ultrices arcu, ut pulvinar risus maximus sed. Quisque dolor nisl, iaculis id sem eget, molestie mollis est. Phasellus scelerisque sagittis ex, nec vestibulum turpis euismod eu.
    Aliquam aliquet orci et sapien euismod, vitae pellentesque velit porttitor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin rhoncus, felis non elementum ultrices, dui nisl tincidunt risus, sit amet
    sodales nunc dolor semper lacus. Vivamus egestas lectus id imperdiet pharetra. Nulla non sem elit. Fusce porta velit leo, nec gravida ligula auctor vitae. Sed justo sem, sodales ut imperdiet at, fringilla pharetra neque.</p>
</div>
<div class="collapse" tabindex="1">
  <h2>Boxinum</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tincidunt ultrices arcu, ut pulvinar risus maximus sed. Quisque dolor nisl, iaculis id sem eget, molestie mollis est. Phasellus scelerisque sagittis ex, nec vestibulum turpis euismod eu.
    Aliquam aliquet orci et sapien euismod, vitae pellentesque velit porttitor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin rhoncus, felis non elementum ultrices, dui nisl tincidunt risus, sit amet
    sodales nunc dolor semper lacus. Vivamus egestas lectus id imperdiet pharetra. Nulla non sem elit. Fusce porta velit leo, nec gravida ligula auctor vitae. Sed justo sem, sodales ut imperdiet at, fringilla pharetra neque.</p>
</div>
<div class="collapse" tabindex="1">
  <h2>Boxinum</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tincidunt ultrices arcu, ut pulvinar risus maximus sed. Quisque dolor nisl, iaculis id sem eget, molestie mollis est. Phasellus scelerisque sagittis ex, nec vestibulum turpis euismod eu.
    Aliquam aliquet orci et sapien euismod, vitae pellentesque velit porttitor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin rhoncus, felis non elementum ultrices, dui nisl tincidunt risus, sit amet
    sodales nunc dolor semper lacus. Vivamus egestas lectus id imperdiet pharetra. Nulla non sem elit. Fusce porta velit leo, nec gravida ligula auctor vitae. Sed justo sem, sodales ut imperdiet at, fringilla pharetra neque.</p>
</div>
<div class="collapse" tabindex="1">
  <h2>Boxinum</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tincidunt ultrices arcu, ut pulvinar risus maximus sed. Quisque dolor nisl, iaculis id sem eget, molestie mollis est. Phasellus scelerisque sagittis ex, nec vestibulum turpis euismod eu.
    Aliquam aliquet orci et sapien euismod, vitae pellentesque velit porttitor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin rhoncus, felis non elementum ultrices, dui nisl tincidunt risus, sit amet
    sodales nunc dolor semper lacus. Vivamus egestas lectus id imperdiet pharetra. Nulla non sem elit. Fusce porta velit leo, nec gravida ligula auctor vitae. Sed justo sem, sodales ut imperdiet at, fringilla pharetra neque.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @JackPirates! Thanks for the suggestion, but I am looking for a solution where when a tab is open and you click on it, it closes as well and not just when you click on another tab.

Comment: then you need to use accordian

Comment: I tried but I couldn't find an accordion that works as I want it. Basically your solution, but with the change that I wrote down above.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: yeah I will remember this thing

Answer (score 0):

This my second post, check if helpful..:)

```js
$('div.accordion-body').on('shown', function () {
    $(this).parent("div");

});

$('div.accordion-body').on('hidden', function () {
    $(this).parent("div");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading"> <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#jai">
        <span class="pull-right"></span>
         Boxinum
       </a>

        </div>
        <div id="jai" class="accordion-body collapse in">
            <div>
                <div class="accordion-inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tincidunt ultrices arcu, ut pulvinar risus maximus sed. Quisque dolor nisl, iaculis id sem eget, molestie mollis est. Phasellus scelerisque sagittis ex, nec vestibulum turpis euismod eu.
    Aliquam aliquet orci et sapien euismod, vitae pellentesque velit porttitor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin rhoncus, felis non elementum ultrices, dui nisl tincidunt risus, sit amet
    sodales nunc dolor semper lacus.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading"> <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
         <span class="pull-right"></span>
         Boxinum
       </a>

        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
            <div>
                <div class="accordion-inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tincidunt ultrices arcu, ut pulvinar risus maximus sed. Quisque dolor nisl, iaculis id sem eget, molestie mollis est. Phasellus scelerisque sagittis ex, nec vestibulum turpis euismod eu.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading"> <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse3">
         <span class="pull-right"></span>
         Boxinum
       </a>

        </div>
        <div id="collapse3" class="accordion-body collapse">
            <div>
                <div class="accordion-inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi @JackPirates again! Thanks for the help, please have a look on the [link](http://codepen.io/csongor_kocsis/pen/vLzEmR) and see what I meant. You can check that when you click on the red div and then the blue one, the red closes and vice versa.